# how to bind sap.ui.Table.TreeTable columns to different type of data

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.ui.Table.TreeTable in sapui5 and want to bind the first column to item and want to display the array of items in second column of each row.

```
 var table = [
               {item:1, items:[{sceondItem:1},{sceondItem:2},{sceondItem:3}]},
               {item:2, items:[{sceondItem:1},{sceondItem:2},{sceondItem:3}]}
        ];
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
        oModel.setData({"modelData":table});
        table.setModel(oModel);
        table.bindRows("/modelData");
```

Comment: You table is not a valid JSON. The items array shouldn't have keys.

Comment: if you dont assign keys how you gonna bind each column to different items in the object ?

Comment: I am not sure about the TreeTable, but an array must not have keys, only a list of values.
For the column-binding,  see the SAPUI5 TreeTable example:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#test-resources/sap/ui/table/demokit/TreeTable.html

Comment: I don't think that's how the TreeTable works; it expects a tree (i.e. hierarchy in the first column, and the remaining columns are used for the data. This implicitly means that parents and childs **must** have the same data structure